# Cannot resolve all parameters for Response error in Jasmine test

Tags: typescript, angular, jasmine

I have this code in my test:

```
import {
  beforeEach, beforeEachProviders,
  describe, xdescribe,
  expect, it, xit,
  async, inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LocalStorage, SessionStorage, WEB_STORAGE_PROVIDERS } from 'h5webstorage';

beforeEachProviders(() => [
  UserService, Http, Response, Observable, ConnectionBackend, LocalStorage, Headers, RequestOptions
]);

describe('Service: UserService', () => {

  it('testtest', inject([UserService], (service) => {
    expect('test').toEqual('test');
  }));
});
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Response'(?). Make sure that
>   all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type
>   annotations and that 'Response' is decorated with Injectable.

Is this because of inproper dependency injection in the test?
How can I do proper dependency injection in a Jasmine test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it for you:

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import {
    beforeEach, 
    addProviders,
    inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

import {BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

import {MockBackend} from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('Service: UserService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => addProviders([
        UserService,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            MockBackend,
            provide(Http, {
                useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                },
                deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
            })
        ]));

    it('testtest', inject([UserService], (service) => {
        expect('test').toEqual('test');
    }));
});
```

You need to provide Http with a factory. Otherwise you will not be able to mock the responses.

Comment: 'How's that for RC4 @stijn26?
`provide` is not a member of `@angular/core/testing` any more. This is not working.

Comment: import { provide } from '@angular/core';